# Using a config file in Microsoft Unit Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Currently for a number of my unit tests I require that some configuration be pulled from a file.  Initially I thought I only needed to add Test Settings to my unit testing project and configure this in Test Settings->Deployment.  I added my config file here but my unit tests were still complaining that they couldn't find this config file.  Finally I found that I needed to add the [DeploymentItem("Test.config")] attribute to any of my unit test classes that needed this.

Is this how it's supposed to be done?  It seems like I should not have to use the DeploymentItem attribute.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the config file to copy to the output directory in a post build

Comment: This seems like it may be a better way of doing it than I currently am but I'm still wondering why this doesn't work when I set the config file up as a Deployment item in the test settings.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that your code under test requires a config file? Then you can add a regular app.config to your unit tests. Well in all other cases you can use that as well.

Comment: It's not an app.config file that the tests require.  It's a custom config file.